# Amazon SNS Mobile push: How do I set expiration time for push on GCM and APNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to control a push message lifetime.

I would like to set expiration time for push message on GCM and APNS using SNS.
(e.g. GCM's "time_to_live" option)

How do I set it? or, SNS is can not control it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found answer by myself.

**SNS is can not manage mobile message lifetime now.**

Thanks.

=================

EDIT.

Amazon SNS added TTL control for mobile push notification.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-ttl.html

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave this here if someone comes across the same question and does not find the official docs straightforward about the config as there is no example on the official AWS. If you are using `aws-sdk` in node you can use this snippet.

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';

AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

const params = {
  'TargetArn' : '<ARN ENDPOINT>',
  'MessageStructure' : 'json',
  'MessageAttributes': {
    'AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS_SANDBOX.TTL': {
      DataType: 'Number',
      StringValue: '7200' // value in seconds
    },
    'AWS.SNS.MOBILE.APNS.TTL': {
      DataType: 'Number',
      StringValue: '7200' // value in seconds
    },
    'AWS.SNS.MOBILE.FCM.TTL': {
      DataType: 'Number',
      StringValue: '7200' // value in seconds
    },
  },
  'Message' : JSON.stringify({
    "GCM": JSON.stringify({
      content_available: true,
      priority: "high",
      notification: {
        body: '<Your message>',
        title: "<Your title>",
        android_channel_id: "<Your channel>",
      }
    }),
    "APNS_SANDBOX" : JSON.stringify({
      'aps' : { 'alert' : '<Your message>' },
    }),
    "APNS" : JSON.stringify({
      'aps' : { 'alert' : '<Your message>' },
    }),
  })
};

sns.publish(params, (error, response) => {});
```

For Windows, Amazon, Baidu service setting parameters see official docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-ttl.html